# SQL Server Client - Server database synchronization with schema

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, data-synchronization

I have have C#.net a application which uses online db server and even local server .

If the user no longer connected to internet he can use offline server in his local machine . but before using offline server he should sync the online server to offline  .

Currently there is stored procedure based model to get & dump data . Since my application is a beta version i get many schema changes in server db now and then . So therefore each time I need to manually run the schema changes on my local machine  or I have to take the deployment script of schema changes and make application to apply this schema to local db before sync .

Time is time consuming and a  extra overhead.

What is the best approach to sync even schema  and data . Can I go for replication ?

In my case i need only Online online to offline sync  . vice versa is not required .

Answer (score 0):

Replication will not work as you have to specify schema in advance.
You could try something like redgate's sql compare but it is not free:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/

Or you could try something along the lines of FluentMigrator, a database migration library for .net:

https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator

Another alternative would be Open DBDiff:

http://opendbiff.codeplex.com/

Again, another free one:

http://www.xsql.com/

The last one has a command line utility for automated data comparison and synchronization.